# Procedimiento almacenado delete SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una duda con un procedimiento almacenado al momento de ejecuarlo me toma demasiados argumentos

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NI_MenusXPefil_D]
    @id_Menuxperfil SMALLINT
      AS
      SET NOCOUNT ON
     DELETE FROM NI_Perfiles_MenuXPerfil WHERE (idMenuXPerfil IN 
     (@id_Menuxperfil))
     IF @@ERROR <> 0
       BEGIN
       SELECT 0 AS [ERROR];
       END
       ELSE
        BEGIN
    SELECT scope_identity() AS [ID];
     END
```

lo que quiero es enviarles diferentes idMenuperfil para eliminar ,
los ejecuto asi que es como me los arroja mi codigo

```
  EXEC [dbo].[SP_NI_MenusXPefil_D] 1,2,3
```

pero me arroja este error
La función o el procedimiento 
SP_NI_MenusXPefil_D tiene demasiados argumentos

si ejecuto el Dele en solo replazando los valores me funciona pero en el Procedimiento almacenado no

Comment: Pues porque le estas enviando varios argumentos 1,2,3, tu variable de entrada es un smallint solo te permitira un solo valor.

Comment: Si como dices necesitas trabajar con varios valores, puedes pasarlos como tal:  `1,2,3`, pero debes modificar la `PROCEDURE`, implementando una consulta preparada: [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150183/5587982)

Comment: Eh intentado con el ejemplo pero no me Funciona el DELETE IN , en el ejemplo todas la consultas preparadas son para select